# Extract facebook pages from url [ios]

Tags: ios, iphone, regex, facebook

my problem is very minor but I can't resolve it.

I have 2 facebook url's:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/**Name_Of_Page**/ID_OF_PAGE

http://www.facebook.com/**Name_Of_Page**

And I need to extract **only the name** by using `NSRegularExpression`.

This is my code:

```
NSRegularExpression* FBregex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"((http|https)://)?([w]{3}\\.)?(facebook\\.com/(pages/)?)" options:0 error:&error];
NSString *result=[FBregex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:STRING_TO_EVALUATE options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [STRING_TO_EVALUATE length]) withTemplate:@""]
```

I need to remove the ID of the page to be shown. Any ideas?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used NSRegularExpressions before, but if it's Perl-Compatible, there are a couple of ways you can get to what you want.

This is a `lookbehind` method.  Lookbehinds do not capture anything, they just mark a position, so the match starts with the character class and ends when it runs into a word boundary.

```
~(?<=pages/)[-A-Z0-9_.]+\b~i
```

This is a `Forget Everything` method.  The `\K` tells the REGEX engine to require the `pages/` to be there, but then forget it.  So, it has the same effect of starting the capture at the character class and ending when it runs into a word boundary.

```
~pages/\K[-A-Z0-9_.]+\b~i
```

Both of these methods will only give you the name of the page.

[Here is a demo](http://regex101.com/r/oK2sJ0)